# Windows 8 List View repeating Columns

Tags: windows-8

I am working on a Windows 8 app where I have to show 4 items in a row in list view. Right now with code I have all items are populate one below another. Could some one please guide me on logic like repeated columns in metro app ListView.
My code is as below ...

```
<ListView x:Name="ItemListView" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Margin="10,190,0,0">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical"  >                      
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding username}" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding value}" />
                <Image Source="{Binding thumb}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use

```
<ListView>
   <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientataion="Horizontal">
   </VirtualizingStackPanel>
</ListView>
```

If it doesn't work you can use `GridView` instead of `ListView`.